# Does Gradle automatically infer dependency between tasks? If so, when?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, build-definition, tooling

In my build script, when I configure the `downloadAndUnzipFile` task, I am explicitly querying output of `downloadZipFile` task. I expected this is sufficient for Gradle to infer a dependency between the tasks, but it apparently is not, because I get an error when invoking downloadAndUnzipFile`.

```
Execution failed for task ':downloadAndUnzipFile'.
> Cannot expand ZIP '/home/jdanek/repos/testing/gradle-infer-deps/build/1.0.zip' as it does not exist.
```

My build script `build.gradle.kts` is

```
import de.undercouch.gradle.tasks.download.Download

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    id("de.undercouch.download").version("4.0.4")
}

tasks {
    val downloadZipFile by registering(Download::class) {
        src("https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/archive/1.0.zip")
        dest(File(buildDir, "1.0.zip"))
    }

    val downloadAndUnzipFile by registering(Copy::class) {
        from(zipTree(downloadZipFile.get().outputFiles.first()))
        into(buildDir)
    }
}
```

I also tried

```
from(zipTree(downloadZipFile.get().outputFiles.first()))
```

and that does not define a dependency either.

My Gradle is the latest 6.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for Gradle to discover task dependencies, they have to use specific types for their inputs and outputs so that Gradle can track the dependencies for you. See [this documentation page](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_task_dependencies_in_lazy_properties) on the topic.

In your use case, the `de.undercouch.download` plugin seems to expose a simple `List<File>` which is not a rich type, so Gradle cannot figure out the link. In that case you have be explicit about the task dependency, using `dependsOn(downloadZipFile)`

Comment: Aha. I'll look into enhancing the `de.undercouch.download` then.

Comment: No chance. The task explicitly aims to support Gradle versions from 2.0 up! Implicit dependencies come in 4.x.